# Помогите подключить файл, который лежит в другой папке, в PHP скрипт

Tags: require, php

Разобрался с ошибкой "FPDF error: Unexpected end of stream", класс FPDF лежит в папке /FPDF/fpdf.php, но если я его подключаю вот так - `require('/FPDF/fpdf.php');`, то выдает ошибку PHP

```
Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '../FPDF/fpdf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20
```

**Подскажите как правильно подключить файл, который лежит в другой папке?**

*Попытался подключить таким способом -*

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/FPDF/fpdf.php');
```

*Но после этого вообще засыпало Ворнингами и Фатал Эррорами(((*

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/FPDF/fpdf.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp:/usr/share/locale) in /home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20

Warning: require(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/FPDF/fpdf.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/usr/local/apache/htdocs/FPDF/fpdf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/u552896297/public_html/createPdfFromBase64.php on line 20
```

Comment: Сорри я уже удалил свой ответ. Он немного не в тему был. То что ты делаешь с require и есть задание абсолютного пути.

Comment: ооо. новый баг у форума нашёл :) Ответ удалил, а уважуха осталась О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тему можно закрывать, я разобрался в чем дело, в конфигурации PHP (php.ini) на этом хостинге не активен **open_basedir**, поэтому и возникли проблемы!